# Open and Reuse same instance of Excel Application

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to open an instance of a Excel Workbook which has data in it, and allow it remain to be opened but hidden from view so to load different data depending on which button the user clicks.

Current setup:
User clicks on "Bird" button, open excel, loads # of birds to VB.NET GUI, close excel
User clicks on "Dog" button, open excel, load # of dogs to VB.NET GUI, close excel
...

Code:

```
Private sub main()

do 
  if(button_dog.clicked = true)
         getdatafromexcel() //gets dog data
  if(button_bird.clicked = true)
         getdatafromexcel() //gets bird data
  if(button_cat.clicked = true)
         getdatafromexcel() //gets cat data
While //User doesn't want to quit
End Main
```

However, I cannot figure out how to setup a constant connection with the Excel workbook so that it runs in the background so that I don't have to re-open it each time the user clicks on a different button. This will dramatically cut down the time needed to load and reload.

You could do this with a SQL database so I should be able to do with this excel...

Comment: Right now I'm contemplating using a multithread approach to open the thing in the background. However I'm not so sure as to how I could pass the opened excel application between the private subroutines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Excel application instance and then hide resp. show it using the [Application.Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.visible%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property of the Excel Application object. You can pass the application as a parameter to your methods. So your code could look like this:

```
Private sub main()
    'instantiate and open excel for the whole main life time
    Dim excelApplication As Excel.Application = Nothing
    excelApplication = New Excel.Application()

    'hide Excel
    excelApplication.Visible = False
    do 'something excel is still open
      if(button_dog.clicked = true)
             getdatafromexcel(excelApplication) 'gets dog data from excelApplication
      if(button_bird.clicked = true)
             getdatafromexcel() 'gets bird data from excelApplication
      if(button_cat.clicked = true)
             getdatafromexcel() 'gets cat data from excelApplication
    While 'User doesn't want to quit

    ' show Excel if you want to
    excelApplication.Visible = True
    ' close Excel
    excelApplication.Workbooks.Close()
    excelApplication.Quit()
    excelApplication = Nothing

End Main
```

The `getdatafromexcel` could look like:

```
Private Sub getdatafromexcel(ByVal excelApp as Excel.Application)
    ' do something with excel
End Sub
```

You could create an enumeration for your button clicks and rewrite your code so you pass the button click enumeration to your method - this would simplify and reduce your code (for example if the decision is made in the getdatafromexcel method).